# Adding custom properties to Express app and req. What's the best way?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Am I shooting myself in the foot:

I want to make config, core, and mean available on the app and req objects in my Express app.

I'm using properties not in the 4.x API.  Anything I should know?

Is there a problem with just adding them as properties?

```
// express.js
module.exports = function(db, config, meanModules) {

  var app = express();

  // ... 

  // Get mean-core
  var core = require('meanjs-core')(db, config);

  // Attach config, core, and modules to app    <==== POSSIBLE FOOT SHOOTING
  app.config = config;
  app.core = core;
  app.mean = meanModules;

  // Middleware to adjust req
  app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    // Add config, core, and modules to all requests  <==== POSSIBLE FOOT SHOOTING
    req.config = config;
    req.core = core;
    req.mean = meanModules;
    next();
  });

  // ...
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to do this in the first place?

Comment: I want to patch controllers and services from other npm packages onto my app.  meanjs-core would have controllers from outside my application.  These could be updated via npm.

e.g. 

    app.route('/auth/confirm/:confirmationCode').get(app.core.users.checkEmailVerification);

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend attaching a single property to app that's probably never going to conflict, and accessing everything from there, like `app.myLibrary`.

```
app.myLibrary = {config: config, core: core, mean: meanModules};
```

And access app.myLibrary from within routes/middleware:

```
req.app.myLibrary
```

Unless something dynamic is happening in the middleware that varies per request, it's likely better to just access it with `req.app.myLibrary`.

Comment: Hey Fury, what do you mean by "unless something dynamic is happening"?  Thanks for the answer!

Comment: The something dynamic could be checking something specific to the request (like checking if it's an XHR and doing something different), or doing a fresh database query, or calling a function. If it's just access to app variables then a middleware function is unnecessary.